# React Native App runs fine in Expo Go, but crashes when clicking a specific button in TestFlight simulator

Tags: react-native, crash, testflight, apple-developer, expo-go

Having a problem where my app runs fine in expo-go, but crashes when I click a certain button in testflight simulator. It's odd because I have four of these buttons, but only one of them causes a crash. No crash feedback is seen on my apple developer account.

Here's the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: ******* [5827]

Triggered by Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x198ee269c __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x191177c80 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   ClimateFund                            0x100a34fd4 0x1008e8000 + 1363924
3   ClimateFund                            0x100aa32b0 0x1008e8000 + 1815216
4   ClimateFund                            0x100aa3ae4 0x1008e8000 + 1817316
5   CoreFoundation                         0x198e27794 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                         0x198e2722c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
7   CoreFoundation                         0x198e27054 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
8   ClimateFund                            0x100a644c4 0x1008e8000 + 1557700
9   ClimateFund                            0x100a66514 0x1008e8000 + 1565972
10  ClimateFund                            0x100a66164 0x1008e8000 + 1565028
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0deb6a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ded300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df4894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df53c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0e00004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0dff878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1b964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1ba04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0555178 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0554f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0554e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0554c68 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x198e2bb1c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x198e29a14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x198e29478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   GraphicsServices                       0x1dc3aa4f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
8   UIKitCore                              0x19b24d62c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9   UIKitCore                              0x19b24cc68 UIApplicationMain + 340
10  ClimateFund                            0x1008efa3c 0x1008e8000 + 31292
11  dyld                                   0x1bbb62dcc start + 2240

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1b9fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e055dfbc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1f680 pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a0ea5b90 abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d49ff8 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d39f90 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19117ada4 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d493bc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202d49360 std::terminate() + 108
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ded314 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df4894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0df53c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0e00004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0dff878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1b964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x202e1ba04 start_wqthread + 8
```